# Uniform Problem - Expected Value

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

A fraternity is throwing a party for its members. The cost of booking a band to play at the party, the amount that the supplier is going to charge, the cost of renting some place and some other costs are random uniform variables over the intervals (1300,1800),(1800,2000),(800,1200) and (400,700) respectively. If the number of people invited is a random integer in the interval (150,200). What is the minimum amount, in average, the fraternity will have to charge each person to not lose money?

What I did was: The sum of all the costs and then the average, that gave me 5000, then the average of the attendees, 175. I divided them. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: I would think about computing the expected cost separately from the number of attendees. It  (somewhat unrealistically) does not depend upon the number of attendees. Then separately think about how to charge attendees as to offset the expected cost.

Comment: I suspect E(cost/attendees) is not what you want but the much easier  E(cost)/E(attendees)

Comment: What I did was: The sum of all the costs and then the average, that gave me 5000, then the average of the attendees, 175. I divided them. But I don't know how to continue.

Comment: Heads up to readers: This appears to be homework fishing: This exact post by same user has been posted, cross-posted, deleted, and re-posted...

Comment: I did not know how to edit the question

Comment: A simulation gives an idea toward a solution without spoiling opportunities to practice addition of means and variances of independent random variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simulation in R of total costs for the party and cost per ticket.

```
set.seed(2021)
m=10^5
x1 = runif(m, 1300, 1800)
x2 = runif(m, 1800, 2000)
x3 = runif(m, 800, 1200)
x4 = runif(m, 400, 700)
t = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4
n = sample(150:200, m, rep=T)

summary(t);  sd(t)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
   4333    4850    5000    5000    5150    5673 
[1] 212.0116
```

You can sum the means of the four uniform distributions
to get the mean of the total cost (about $\$5000).$ Also, you can sum
the variances of these four distributions (provided they're independent) to get the
variance of the total cost; the take the square root to
get the standard deviation (about $\$212.)$ The distribution is not exactly normal but nearly normal.

```
hist(t, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Simulated Dist'n of Cost")
```

[image]

```
summary(t/n)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  21.88   26.62   28.55   28.77   30.81   37.40 
q = quantile(t/n, .95);  q
     95% 
33.45204 
hist(t/n, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Approx. Dist'n per Ticket")
 abline(v = q, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

If the probability models for costs and attendance are correct, the fraternity is unlikely to lose
money charging $\$33.50$ per ticket. [If the ticket price were set at $\$28.55$ (median of distribution) there would be a 50:50 chance of losing money.]

Comment: Hello @BruceET, Thaaanks you!! Why in the end you suggest taking the median and not the mean?

Comment: Because median has half of probability below below and half above. // Dist'n of Cost is almost normal, for which mean and median are identical. However dist'n of Cost per ticket is skewed so mean and median are (a little) different.

Answer (score 1):

The question in the exercise points IMO to an exercise where a so called **"fair price"** is to be calculated, which means that the expected costs should be equal to the expected revenue from the price.

You almost did the job already:

Expected costs: $5000$

Expected number of attendees: $175$

Fair price $p$: $5000 = 175p \Rightarrow p = \frac{200}7 \approx 28.57143$.

If you want to be picky, you may round it up to $28.58$ in order not to loose money "in average" (as the exercise text requires).

Comment: The average of a quotient, is not just the quotient of the average.

Comment: @jMdA Of course not. But the context of the exercise looks rather like a fair-price question. Let's the OP decide what the intention of the question was.

Comment: @jMdA Or what are your arguments against that the expected costs are $5000$ and the expected revenue is $175p$?
Of course there is plenty of opportunity to over-complicate this problem.

Comment: @jMdA Letting $X=$ expenses and $N=$ # guests, I think it is correct to charge $E[X]/E[N]$. This ensures that $E[\text{money lost}]=E[X-\text{price}\cdot N]=E[X-E[X]/E[N]\cdot N]=0$, so the frat does not lose money on average. The value $E[X/N]$ is irrelevant.